# result of postgresql xlog dump

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, wal

I am using PostgreSQL db in Ubuntu. I got to know about WAL logs and pg_xlogdump. I used pg_xlogdump to print the WAL logs on screen. But I have no idea how to interpret the response and to know what transactions were made.

Answer (score 0):

To read and understand `pg_xlogdump` output, you must know something about PostgreSQL's internals.

The `desc` will tell you what operation took place (something like `NEXTOID` or `INSERT_LEAF`) as well as further details (e.g., what the next `Oid` was or at which offset in which block of which file the new index entry was added).

You'll have to read [the source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sourcerepo.html) to understand the different entry types.

Comment: And where will I find that..?

Comment: I though that was obvious. I have added a link.